# Partial mocked class: use mockedBean inside other mockedBean

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito

For a unit-test I want to mock a class only in part using `willCallRealMethod()`. However it seems like the `@Autowired` dependecies inside the partly mocked class are not overridden with the `@MockBean` I defined.

The class I'm trying to test looks someting like this:

```
@Service
public class TestableClass {

    @Autowired
    private TestableDependency testableDependency;

    public String testableMethod(final String param) {
        String result = this.someMethod(param);
        return testableDependency.anotherMethod(result);
    }

    public String someMethod(final String param) {
        return param + " :)";
    }
}
```

And here is what the test class looks like.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@Profile("test")
public class TestableClassTest {
    @MockBean
    private TestableClass testableClass;

    @MockBean
    private TestableDependency testableDependency;

    @Test
    public void testableMethodTest() {
        given(this.testableClass.someMethod("Hello").willReturn("Hello :)");
        given(this.testableDependency.anotherMethod("Hello :)").willReturn("Hello :) How are you?");
        given(this.testableClass.testableMethod("Hello").willCallRealMethod();

        String result = this.testableClass.testableMethod("Hello");

        assertThat(result)
        .isEqualTo("Hello :) How are you?");
    }
}
```

The issue is that the `testableDependency` in `testableClass` is not ovverriden by the `testableDependency` I defined in the `TestableClassTest`. Or at least I think so because when I use the debugger I end up in org.mockito.internal.invocation.RealMethod

If I change `testableClass` in `TestableClassTest` from `@MockBean` to `@Autowired` it might work but then I can't mock `someMethod` anymore. How can I achieve both?

Comment: you should not mock internal method calls. You should let the flow go through the internal methods. If someMethod calls some other class then, you should mock that call. And by the way you cannot mock internal calls (atleast with Mockito)

Comment: https://springframework.guru/mockito-mock-vs-spy-in-spring-boot-tests/

Comment: Thanks for your comment. someMethod makes an http call so i have to mock it somehow. Do you have a solution for that ?

Comment: @SvenKeinath if it is your code, you should separate http logic and encapsulate it in "mockable dependency"

Comment: @piradian Thanks for your help. Works just fine after I applied the changes you suggested :)

Comment: @SvenKeinath I'm glad I could help :).